# Const member stack vs heap

Tags: c++, constructor

If I try to compile [this code](http://ideone.com/79wLGv)

```
struct A {
    const int j;
};
A a;
```

I'll get an expected error:

> error: uninitialized const member in ‘struct A’

but, if I try to compile [this one](http://ideone.com/uKwdaO):

```
struct A {
    const int j;
};
A * a = new A();
```

I'll get a successful build.

The question is: why does `new` allocation allows creating a variable with const member without explicit constructor and stack allocation - doesn't ?

Comment: Doesn't compile with GCC 4.9 or Clang. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fadd1a456bfd5b82

Comment: @remyabel Which obviously says nothing about the correctness of this code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's not because of the heap allocation, but because of the *parenthesis* you use when allocating. If you do e.g.

```
A* a = new A;
```

it would also fail.

The reason it works when you add the parenthesis is because then your structure is value initialized, and for a POD-type like `A` value-initialization value-initializes each member, and the default value-initialization for `int` is zero.

That means it would probably work creating the variable on the stack as well, if you just add the value-initialization parenthesis:

```
A a = A(); // watch out for the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse
```

Though that brings other potential problems, better use uniform initialization if you can (requies C++11):

```
A a{};
```

Comment: Yeah it would be assumed as a function declaration.

Comment: `A a = A();` would work, but does `A a{};` really work?

Comment: Ok. Thank you. Did I understand right: if I write `()` after variable then **for POD types** there's no c-tor calling but only doing members initialization ?

Answer (score 6):

This is ill-formed as of C++14. §12.1 [class.ctor] says that

> 4 A defaulted default constructor for class X is defined as deleted
>   if:
>
> - [...]
> - any non-variant non-static data member of const-qualified type (or array thereof) with no *brace-or-equal-initializer* does not have a
>     user-provided default constructor,
> - [...]
>
> A default constructor is trivial if it is not user-provided and if:
>
> - its class has no virtual functions (10.3) and no virtual base classes (10.1), and
> - no non-static data member of its class has a *brace-or-equal-initializer*, and
> - all the direct base classes of its class have trivial default constructors, and
> - for all the non-static data members of its class that are of class type (or array thereof), each such class has a trivial default
>     constructor.

§8.5 [dcl.init] says in turn that

> 7 To default-initialize an object of type T means:
>
> - if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type (Clause 9), the default constructor (12.1) for T is called (and the initialization is
>     ill-formed if T has no default constructor or overload resolution
>     (13.3) results in an ambiguity or in a function that is deleted or
>     inaccessible from the context of the initialization);
> - [...]
>
> 8 To value-initialize an object of type T means:
>
> - if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type (Clause 9) with either no default constructor (12.1) or a default constructor that is
>     user-provided or deleted, then the object is default-initialized;
> - [...]

The empty pair of parentheses results in value-initialization. The default constructor for `A` is defined as deleted per [class.ctor]/p4. Thus, by [dcl.init]/p8, value-initialization means default-initialization, and by p7 the initialization is ill-formed because the constructor is deleted.

The C++11 version actually allowed value-initialization in this context; it says for value-initialization that, among other things,

> if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) non-union class type without a
>   user-provided constructor, then the object is zero-initialized and, if
>   T’s implicitly-declared default constructor is non-trivial, that
>   constructor is called.

Since by the definition above the default constructor is trivial (even though it is deleted), it is not actually called. This was considered a defect in the standard and the relevant wording was changed by [CWG issue 1301](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1301).

Compiler vendors usually do implement defect resolutions, so this could be considered a bug in GCC 4.8 that's been fixed in 4.9.